# how to tar all files in a directory and move that tar to another directory

Tags: linux, tar

So I have 2 directors A and B.  I want to tar all the files in A and have the .tar file be sent to directory B.  How can i do this?

I have tried

```
sudo tar -C /home/mine/A/  -cvf home/mine/B/test.tar
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
```

Comment: is there anything in `/home/mine/A/`?

Comment: yes i have 4 files in there

Comment: you shouldn't need `sudo` to tar up some files, FWIW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tar -cvf /home/mine/B/test.tar /home/mine/A/
```

works fine for me.